# How to open files in VSCode like PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I've recently switched from PyCharm to VSCode and the relative paths in my previous projects developed in PyCharm no longer work in VSCode.

In general I want to be able to import functions from various scripts based on the root project directory. However, when specifying paths to open files (i.e. with open('somepath.txt')...), I want to use relative paths from the file that's calling the open, not from the root.

I was able to do this in PyCharm and I like how compact it makes the paths. How can I replicate this behaviour in VSCode?

I've tried setting `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true` but this make it so that importing from other files is no longer relative to the root directory. However, if it set that setting to False, VSCode searches for files to open from the root directory which is not what I want.

Comment: In VSCode, the Python extension starts the Python interpreter with the workspace folder that contains the file as the working directory. So, you can use absolute imports for your modules and use the `__file__` variable to get the path of the current script for file operations.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want but that's what I would do, especially if the code may be use by other people in the future.

If you absolutely want this behavior, you should enforce it programmatically and not rely on IDE options.

To always open files relatively to the file that is making the call you can define the relative path using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` within that file and specify the full path like: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), <folder1>, ..., <folderN>, <filename>)`